# How to block the culprit of the unknown port?

Tags: linux, networking, security, port

When I did a port scan `nmap -p- localhost` of my local system I found some unknown ports opened. I was using a closed source application when this happened and I known its this causing port opening. Everytime I open this software it uses a different port.

To find the process associated with the port I used `sudo lsof -i TCP:48292`

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
somefunc  12819  eka    3u  IPv4 2132143      0t0  TCP localhost:48292 (LISTEN)
```

This closed source software is always using `somefunc` command to open random ports on everyrun.

How can I block this command from opening any more ports?

Edit: Its confirmed this closed source software is running `somefunc`. I found the source directory using `pwdx 12819`

Comment: If I had no choice but to run it I would do so in a VM and firewall it to hell.

Comment: Depending on what this closed source application does, it may be perfectly legitimate behaviour, and blocking it may cause it to stop working. If you are worried, sandbox it (in a network namespace, or VM), and monitor the traffic to the sandbox to see if anything interesting happens.

Comment: @dirkt It may or may not be malicious. There are two reasons why I dont want this open port first it doesn't need any kind of connections for its normal function and second I have installed this closed soure app using root level. I will try to sandbox this can you recommend any good one?

Comment: @Eka: How do you know for sure that it doesn't need any connections? The socket is not open to the network -- it is bound to `localhost`, which is _very_ common for inter-process communications (i.e. between two components of the program, or between daemon and UI). (For the same reason, there's not much point in sandboxing it.)